# Can't loop through JSON Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, object

I'm trying to loop through a JSON object using javascript. The reason that it is an object and not an array is because the same data is accessed using XAMARIN and C#'s NewtonJSON works better with *just* JSON Objects instead of a mix of objects and arrays.

Below is the JSON object that I am trying to work with, I've cut bits out so you can see the main part of the object that I'm having issues with.

```
CODE: NULL
VALUE:{
  USER24:{id: "24", business: "25", username: "test1", firstName: "test1", lastName: "test1", level: "0",…}
  USER25:{id: "25", business: "25", username: "test2", firstName: "test2", lastName: "test2", level: "0",…}
  USER26:{id: "26", business: "25", username: "test3", firstName: "test3", lastName: "test3", level: "0",…}
  USER27:{id: "27", business: "25", username: "test4", firstName: "test4", lastName: "test4",…}
  USER28:{id: "28", business: "25", username: "test5", firstName: "test5", lastName: "test5",…}
  USER29:{id: "29", business: "25", username: "test6", firstName: "test6", lastName: "test6", level: "0",…}
  USER30:{id: "30", business: "25", username: "test7", firstName: "test7", lastName: "test7", level: "0",…}
}
EXTRA: NULL
```

The issue I'm having is when I loop through `data.VALUE` I get the keys and values of `USER24` instead of the keys and values of `data.VALUE`. When I try and loop through just `data` I get the keys `CODE`, `VALUE`, `EXTRA` like I would expect.

No matter what I place in the loop I won't get the keys and values `USER24`, `USER25`, `USER26`, ... which I want. Below I have snippet of the Javascript loop I'm using:

```
for(var key in data.VALUE){
  if(data.VALUE.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log('key:'+key+', val:'+data.VALUE[key]);
  }
}
```

All I get back from this is:

```
key:id, val:24
key:business, val:25
key:username, val:test1
key:firstName, val:test1
key:lastName, val:test1
key:level, val:0
key:email, val:test1@test.co.uk
key:phone, val:null
key:isAdmin, val:true
```

Which is completely wrong!

I'm not sure what else I am to do for this, I've tried using `$.each` from JQuery, I've not used the new `let[key, value]` as it's far too new at the moment to rely on.

Here is a picture of the JSON in the preview tab in chrome (minus some sensitive data):

[image]

Comment: The JSON doesnt look valid, whats the format of the `data` variable in JavaScript?

Comment: `console.log` the `data.VALUE` right before the loop. Does that return the object you expect?

Comment: `for(var key in data.VALUE)`. You are get each key in data.VALUE, so of course you would not get USER24,USER25,etc.

Comment: It just seems to work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z3jL4awg/). Make sure your JSON is valid

Comment: When 'console.log''ing the data.VALUE I also just get the USER24 object. I want to be able to loop through each object in data.VALUE and I thought 'for(var key in data.VALUE)' would be able to do that.

Comment: Working fine when I checked : https://jsfiddle.net/mcufctbr/2/

Comment: Mine worked fine too

Comment: Show us how you claim the JSON variable please, in JSFiddle or snippet, whatever

Comment: Javascript objects are weird sometimes.  Since `console.log(data.VALUE)` (check the previous comment) returns USER24 object, it really is not an array. In Javascript you can also put getters and setters on properties, or change the `toString` method. This could explain why your console representation looks like you described, but it actually is totally different. In this case, I'm very sure it is not what you think it is. Please also describe where you get the data from.

Comment: Okay after looking for how I claimed the JSON variable I noticed I didn't actually claim the one I was trying to loop through as it came from an AJAX request and I forgot to include the data, so it was still trying to loop through one from an ajax request before. Sorry for that but thank you so much for bringing my attention to it and thanks to everyone else for all their suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `$.each` from JQuery like this

```
$.each(data.VALUE, function (i, key) {
    $.each(key, function (j,k) {
        console.log('key:'+j+', val:'+k);
    });
});
```

If you want to  access it from javascript you get each key in the `data.VALUE.USER24` object.

```
for (var key in data.VALUE.USER24) {
  if(data.VALUE.USER24.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log('key:' + key + ', val:' + data.VALUE.USER24[key]);
  }
}
```